# Books series where aliens are associated with classical elements

Tags: story-identification, novel

I remember reading these books a long time ago.

- In each book a new alien race is discovered.
- Each alien race is associated with a classical element: fire, water, etc.
- They fight each other while Humans (or a humanoid race) is stuck trying to deal with the fallout.
- There were about 5 books in the series.
- I think the "fire-type" aliens where called the Furios(?) or something similar if that helps.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is [The Saga of Seven Suns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Saga_of_Seven_Suns). There are actually seven books.

The elemental aliens are the

1. hydrogues (air)
2. faeros (fire)
3. wentals (water)
4. verdani (earth)

There are other, non-elemental aliens: the Ildirans and the extinct Klikiss.